# What is the best way to create folders in res to layouts in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen

I have 4 folders in my res folder for layouts:
(layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xxhdpi (for Galaxy S4)).

With some apps I made, the xxhdpi was used automaticaly for the Galaxy S3.
In the app I am building now, the layout on Galaxy S3 remains a mess.

Do I have to make an xhdpi folder for this device or does it exist a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider refactoring of your layout: I don't belive that well-done layout for xxhdpi or hdpi will be "mess" on xhdpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. S3 will pick up from `xhdpi`, if available.

See http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Comment: Create other folther is the best way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes. And don't forget to have the corresponding resources in there :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's work in res

1. layout-xlarge
2. layout-large
3. layout-normal
4. layout-small

and create same xml in different size layout folder so that you can custom layout in different size device